# If $\phi:G\to H$ is an isomorphism, prove that $o(x)=o(\phi(x))$ for all $x\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\phi:G\to H$  is an isomorphism, prove that $o(x)=o(\phi(x))$ for all $x\in G$

My current thought: $\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n$. Thus,$\phi(g^n)=\phi(e)=\phi(g)^n$. However, I don't know how to proceed from here. Also, does my previous steps work when the order of $g$ is infinite?

Comment: If $G$ has infinite order and $g\in G$ then what are the possible orders of $g$?

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ commands in order to display your equations better.

Comment: @crispypizza must also be infinite, right?

Comment: While this may seem like the case, it is not always true. Take a look at the quotient group $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.